# Unpivot Column With Condition in Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, databricks, unpivot

I Have this table named 'Billing' with column ID, current, past, and expired.
Current, past, and expired columns have 'X' value to indicate the status of each IDs. Whether it's current, past, or expired.

[Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPGd9.png)

I want convert keep the status in one column named Category like this:

[Desired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZig.jpg)

What should I do to get this result?
Thank you.